# Include divi section on php page

Tags: divi-theme

I'm trying to add a divi section to a php page (these are documentation pages which we generate automatically with a build script). The code snippet below works for non-divi shortcodes, but not for the divi shortcodes.

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-load.php");
get_header();
...
echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="9822"][/et_pb_section]');
...
getfooter();
```

Instead of getting rendered the shortcode itself is shown on the page.
Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution here:
https://liampedleydesign.co.uk/placing-divi-modules-anywhere-using-shortcodes/

The shortcode code is slightly different for Divi:

`echo do_shortcode('[showmodule id="9822"]');`

Comment: I had been on that page before and tried it out. I just tried it again and it doesn't work for me.   The recipe on that page describes adding a custom shortcode "showmodule" and calling the "et_pb_section" shortcode from there.  When I do that I see that my custom shortcode is called indeed, but the et_pb_section not.  I get the same output as if I added the et_pb_section shortcode directly on my page.

My suspicion is that the divi shortcodes are not getting initialized - maybe because it recognizes it wasn't created with the builder?

Comment: I wondered that as well. Maybe include the following in the top of the page to include the theme files (before the line where you require wp-load.php):
`define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );`

Comment: Been there, done that, and it doesn't resolve the issue.  It's clear that my divi child theme is correctly seen as active in the php file: my custom shortcode is working correctly.